# changing the y axis label of a bar plot to "percentage" in ggplot2

Tags: r

I changed the y axis to percentages using the following code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

p <- ggplot(mydataf, aes(x = foo)) +  
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

That helped, but the label is now: (count)/sum(count) 
and I want it to be: percentage

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: `p + labs(y="percentage")`

Comment: In addition, you can try `aes(y=..density..)`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(scales)

p + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

That should do it.